# Particle Photon make simple HTTPS request (no parsing)

Tags: arduino, particle-photon

I wish to make a "simple" HTTPS request from my particle photon - I don't care about the response, it's just a trigger.

I'm not too good with the Arduino language, but I found [this library](https://github.com/glowfishAPI/httpsclient-particle),  which I included in my code (via the Particle Build Platform).

A link to some tutorial or docs using this lib would be highly appreciated, since my googling didn't gice me anything I could figure out how to do.

Comment: And your question is..? Surely you're **not** asking that we write code for you, right? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not asking for the code. Just a link to some tutorial using https request

Comment: Wrong site for such question. If you have a specific coding problem, with code that doesn't work, ask here. See the links I gave you. Your question is not for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this tutorial (and would like to share it): https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/projects/maker-kit/#tutorial-2-next-bus-alert

This is the way to do it:

Create a webhook via https://console.particle.io/

[image]

Then the params

[image]

Requesting the webhook in your code in https://build.particle.io

```
   ...
   // HTTPS REQUEST
    String data = String(1);
    Particle.publish("RequestName", data, PRIVATE);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18415426)

Comment: You are right - updated my answer. Please remove you down-vote, thx